OpenApi spec with additional properties giving empty response for generated class variables
I am using Openapi spec that has additional properties. The generated response class which extends HashMap<String, Object> has its own properties and when I set values to that Response class properties it is giving empty response {}. Only values set in HashMap are showing. Is there any way to send values back?
RetrieveDataEventRs retrieveDataEventRs = new RetrieveDataEventRs();
retrieveDataEventRs.eventName(sharedServicePackage.getName());
return new ResponseEntity(retrieveDataEventRs, HttpStatus.OK);

Giving empty response {}
Generated class:
I tried setting values and send back and expecting Json response.
